# ToString exception while printing enum

Tags: .net, f#

Given I have an enum:

```
type Cool = A = 'a'
          | B = 'b'
```

And i try to print it like so

```
printf "%A" Cool.A
```

I get the following exception:

> ToString exception: The value passed in must be an enum base or an
>   underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32. Parameter name: value

Why does this happen and (if possible) how I can fix this at the enum level?

Comment: Works fine for me on `fsi v2.0.0.0` (no exception, prints `a`).  Your definition is slightly unidiomatic - F# doesn't tend to use the ocaml style - it would normally be `type Cool = |A='a'|B='b'`

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behaviour with F# 2.0/.NET Framework 4.0 either.

Comment: are you sure that you are printing with the %A placeholder? It's there that lies the problem i think

Comment: I'm using F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1

Comment: This was what I ran / got - `type Cool =
  |  A  =  'a'
  |  B  =  'b'

> printf "%A" Cool.A
- ;;
aval it : unit = ()`

Comment: Works fine here with VS2012 RTM as well.

Comment: My `fsi` is F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1. I think the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro this on a machine with F# 2.0 compiler targeting .Net 4.0, but not with F# 2 targeting .Net 3.5 or less, or on a VS2012 (F# 3.0) machine (where .Net 4.5 supersedes 4.0).

I am not sure right now of the cause, but hopefully this info may help you or others narrow it down or find a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better not to use `char` as base value for `enum`.
Although `char` seems to be allowed ([MSDN article on F# enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233216%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), the corresponding [article for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says the opposite. Moreover, [an older article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.71%29.aspx) says specifically:

> *base-type (Optional)*
>     The underlying type that specifies the storage allocated for each enumerator. It can be one of the integral types **except char**. The default is int.

Looking at the [source code](http://typedescriptor.net/System.Enum.ToObject%28Type,Object%29) of `System.Enum.ToObject(Type,Object)`, it is also evident that `char` is not supported.

So, *even if F# performs special handling* of `enum<char>`, better to avoid it, keeping yourself from future integration problems.